# Python for loop int has no .value

Tags: python

Trying to do something that would be trivial in other languages I know, but I can't figure out how to format it in Python:

```
myList = [2, 3, 4]
for index in range (0, len(myList):
    <external command> = index
    <do some other stuff>
```

However, this seems to draw `index.value` and attempts to use it for the assignment. And since an `int` doesn't have `.value`, it raises an error. Is this a problem with my 'external command' doing something weird with the input? I didn't write the 'external command' so I'm not super sure what it could be doing.

if I explicitly type

```
'<external command> = 2'
```

the command doesn't raises an error. Is there any way to use the raw value in this context?

Comment: Your for loop lacks a closed parentheses, check it. Also post the exact error message please.

Answer (score 0):

As python start list index from 0 so `len(myList)` is 3 and there is no index with value of 3

```
  myList = [2, 3, 4]

  for index in range (0, len(myList) - 1):

        <external command> = index

        <do some other stuff>
```

Comment: sure that is true; I realize the mistake. However, my issue is occurring before we even get to that case. So it's not really the answer I'm looking for.